# Counting pixels in all distinct regions in an image using OpenCV

Tags: python, arrays, image, opencv, image-processing

I have an image that looks like this (it's blown up, but each square is just one pixel). I'd like to be able to count the number of pixels in every black region. Region is defined as horizontally and vertically adjacent pixels (not diagonally). So in this image there are four of them. The output could be either some kind of dictionary with region identifiers (like centroids maybe) mapped to the number of pixels in that region, or just a list of totals would be fine like [14, 3, 9, 9].

[image]

I can't seem to figure out how to get the actual number of pixels to work.

Also, the closest I could find was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59587467/opencv-per-color-pixel-count-in-irregularly-shaped-area) and I still couldn't get it to work for me.

I got this far in my Googling of how the connectedComponentsWithStats function works. I tried blurring the image and everything to get rid of the possible "diagonal" connections. I'm assuming it's the one I'm supposed to use, but maybe there is something better?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2

d = [[9, 8, 9, 3, 2], [8, 7, 8, 9, 1], [9, 6, 5, 8, 9], [9, 7, 6, 7, 9], [9, 8, 7, 8, 9], [6, 9, 8, 9, 4], [5, 6, 9, 4, 3], [6, 7, 8, 9, 2], [7, 8, 9, 2, 1], [8, 9, 2, 1, 0]]
a = np.array([[0 if x < 9 else 255 for x in z] for z in d])

img = Image.fromarray(a.astype(np.uint8), mode='L')
img.save("test.jpg")

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (1, 1), 0)

components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(blurred, connectivity = 4)
output
```

Comment: Don’t blur the image. Just change the `connectivity` In `connectedComponentsWithStats()` to 4 instead of 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connectedComponentsWithStats` **already** gives you `area`, which is the count of pixels in each component (of non-zero pixels) that can be found in the picture.

```py
a = np.where(np.array(d) < 9, 255, 0).astype(np.uint8)

(nlabels, labels, stats, centroids) = cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(a, connectivity=4)

assert nlabels == 5 # = background + 4 components
print(stats[:, cv.CC_STAT_AREA]) # area: array([15, 14,  3,  9,  9], dtype=int32)
```

Pay attention to **Beaker's comment**: CC has a connectivity parameter, which you should set to "4-way".

You should **invert** your picture, so the black pixels become white. white is non-zero is true and that's always foreground, which is what the CC call expects to work with.

Documentation:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gac7099124c0390051c6970a987e7dc5c5

The gaussian blur will turn any binarized image into a soup of grayscale values. **Don't apply the gaussian blur**, or if you **require** it, then threshold afterwards. connectedComponents* will threat any non-zero (!) pixel as foreground

Comment: My connectivity has been set to 4 the whole time, as you can see in my code. I guess i don't understand where this area parameter is. I saw that it's cv. CC_STAT_AREA, but which element do i apply that to? components.CC_STAT_AREA didn't work. And I changed it so the segments are made up of white pixels, but the first component in connectedComponentsWithStats returns "3", which there should be 4 segments. So the whole thing is very confusing to me :(

Comment: could you provide an example maybe?

Comment: you're gonna need to provide exact data first. that illustration isn't entirely black and white, and it has single-pixel black lines near the border. I would have to correct these things.

Comment: The code to generate the image is literally in my post..... The picture looks different because I had to blow it up and take a screenshot ........ I can upload the 5x10 pixel pic when I get home here in few. I just thought it'd be easier to post the snippet.

Comment: oh, there is the data. I didn't pay attention.

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work by any chance?

Comment: "manage"? I didn't even try because there's no question that it'd work. did you? interactive prompt: `a = np.where(np.array(d) < 9, 255, 0).astype(np.uint8); (nlabels, labels, stats, centroids) = cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(a, connectivity=4); nlabels; labels; stats; centroids` and the area is column 4 (the last one), and first row is background

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count pixels, OpenCV has a function for that: [`cv2.countNonZero`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaa4b89393263bb4d604e0fe5986723914). This counts white pixels, but you can easily count black pixels by first computing the image height and width.

Your code would be modified as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2


d = [[9, 8, 9, 3, 2], [8, 7, 8, 9, 1], [9, 6, 5, 8, 9], [9, 7, 6, 7, 9], [9, 8, 7, 8, 9], [6, 9, 8, 9, 4],
     [5, 6, 9, 4, 3], [6, 7, 8, 9, 2], [7, 8, 9, 2, 1], [8, 9, 2, 1, 0]]
a = np.array([[0 if x < 9 else 255 for x in z] for z in d])

img = Image.fromarray(a.astype(np.uint8), mode='L')
img.save("test.jpg")

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')

# Display image:
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (1, 1), 0)

# Count number of white pixels:
whitePixels = cv2.countNonZero(blurred)

print("White pixels: "+str(whitePixels))

# Get image height and width:
(imgHeight, imgWidth) = blurred.shape[:2]

# Get number of black pixels:
blackPixels = imgHeight*imgWidth - whitePixels

print("Black pixels: "+str(blackPixels))
```

Which prints:

```
White pixels: 34
Black pixels: 16
```

**Pro-tip:** Do not use the `jpg` image format, it is lossy - it will compress and modify the value of your pixels. Use a lossless format such as `png`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant I want to count them for each region separately. As in have some kind of mapping, like from centroid to the number of pixels in that region.